# Using Progress Bar in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building an application which read data from pdf files and insert into database. For this purpose I have methods and I want to add an progress bar with showing completed task percentage with the back ends methods. How can I add a progress bar for this purpose. I am using VS 2013. 
For example I have

```
method.1();
method.2();
method.3();
method...();
...........
```

And I want my progress bar show the progress of these method completed.

Comment: [sample code ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/449594/Progress-Bars-Threads-Windows-Forms-and-You) look at this article which may help.

Comment: Do you want to show all methods progress in same 'ProgressBar' or in separate 'ProgressBar's? Are your methods called in a sequence or in separate threads? If you run on different threads then you cannot use the same 'ProgressBar'.

Comment: All method in same progress bar. My method called in a sequence. @Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Assume `progressBar` as your Progress Bar

Define it as public static

Here is the method

```
public static void reportProgress(int incValue) {
    progressBar.Value += incValue;
}
```

and if you are transferring data make progressbars max value to amount of data you will transfer and use this method to increase value of it by adding bytes you have transferred

To set Progress Bars max value

```
progressBar.Maximum(bytesOfData);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to initialize Progress bar

```
progressBar.Value = 0;
progressBar.Maximum= MethodsCount;
```

To keep your progress bar updated you need to use new thread to call all methods that you want to execute like this

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
            {
                //Call your methods 
                //Method1();
                //then you need to call dispatcher to update the progress bar value because you are using a different Thread 
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{ progressBar.Value += 1;});
                //Method2();
            });
```

Comment: I need some help.I am using Progress bar first time  :D.   At line
`Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { progressBar.Value +=1;});`|
what should be actual parameters of this? @Tama

Comment: in this line you just increase the value of progress bar, but we used this dispatcher because when you want to deal with any UI element you should use the main thread of the application

Comment: But i am not getting `.Current.Dispacther` after Application .
Need to include a header?

Comment: I think you need to add these :using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Windows;

Comment: System.Threading.Tasks and System.Windows included but System.Windows.Windows.Threading in not working (there is nothing like this in intellitrace).

Comment: you need to add reference for this dll "WindowsBase"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87663/discussion-between-hanni-and-tama).

Comment: There is a problem. This isn't working. Error detail is the method is accessed from another thread than it was created on. How to handle this problem?? @Tama